# How to get parents of child objects of another specific parent object in a single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

**EXPLANATION**

In my Rails 5 application I have,

Parent model `order.rb`

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Child model `task.rb`

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :rider
end
```

`rider.rb`

```
class Rider < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Parent and Task attributes `schema.rb`

```
create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "status"
  t.boolean  "urgent"
  t.date     "schedule"
  t.integer  "customer_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_orders_on_company_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_orders_on_customer_id", using: :btree
end


create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.boolean  "task_type"
  t.string   "details"
  t.string   "address"
  t.string   "nearby"
  t.float    "lat"
  t.float    "lng"
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "contact"
  t.time     "time"
  t.string   "item_type"
  t.integer  "order_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "rider_id"
  t.integer  "status"
  t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_order_id", using: :btree
end
```

Now let's assume,

- I have 3 `orders` in my database, each `order` has 5 `tasks`.
- 1 out of 5 `tasks` of first 2 `orders` belongs to this rider `my_rider = Rider.find(1)`
- So basically, no matter how many `tasks` are there in an `order`, if a `rider` has any of the `task` assigned, when we show `@assigned_orders` on `my_rider` dashboard there should be all the `orders` in which `my_rider` has a `task` assigned, which in my case is the first 2 out of 3 `orders`.
- I don't know if I explained it right :/

**PROBLEM**

- I want to show the `@assigned_orders` of `my_rider` on his dashboard.
- I want my `ActiveRecord` to make a single query and get all `orders` along with the their `tasks`.

I tried this,

```
my_rider = Rider.find(1)
@assigned_orders = Task.joins(:order).where(rider: my_rider)
```

But it gives me the `tasks` objects in `@assigned_orders` instance variable not the `orders`.

I cannot query with the Parent (`Order`) model because it has no association with the `Rider` model.

Please help me find a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as ABC. Add `has_many :through` association, to set up a connection between `riders` and `orders`.

```
class Rider < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :orders, -> { distinct }, through: :tasks
end
```

And then use it.

```
my_rider = Rider.find(1)
@assigned_orders = my_rider.orders
```

You can also do it without the association.

```
@assigned_orders = Order.joins(:tasks).where(tasks: {rider_id: my_rider.id}).distinct
```

Comment: Perfect! This was needed. I used your first solution of adding up a new association. But can you just explain me a little more about it? Like, how does this association works? Is `through` the magic word here? I thought we only use this when we have a third table to resolve a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: In fact, it is exactly a many-to-many relationship. A `rider` is connected with many `orders` (through `tasks`), and an `order` may be connected with many `riders` (through `tasks`). You are right, the `through` word does the work here. It shows that the connection is using a third table.

Comment: But in my case I don't have a third table and it works just fine. Then why do we need a third table when we can make it work without it?

Comment: `tasks` is the third table. `riders` is connected with `orders` through the third table which is `tasks`

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have `rider_id` column in your tasks table. Therefore I guess you can make the following query:

```
Order.joins(:tasks).where(tasks: { rider_id: my_rider.id }).distinct
```

Comment: Thanks! It is also a right solution but I found @chumakoff first solution more understandable for me. Btw you forgot to add `.distinct` constraint at the end.